# How to print large ERD diagrams done in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a large ERD diagram done in MySQL Workbench and I also have a large format printer. Does anyone know of a way to convert this project to a JPG so that I can print it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Open your ERD and then go to `File`->`Export` and you'll find there that you can export the whole model to PNG or SVG which you can convert later to JPEG if you want to.

Comment: What if I need to export as image every table object individually?

Comment: @Metafaniel, have you found any solution?

Comment: @RNA Hi, I haven´t found a better and more automatic way to do this yet. Sorry...